# How to remove the default margin in create-react-app?

Tags: css, reactjs, create-react-app, margin

I made a new app using the `create-react-app` command. I removed most of the files in the `src` folder. So now my folder looks like this:

[image]

`index.js` has

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

And `App.js` includes

```
import React from 'react'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Now, when I run `yarn start` and go to my browser, it shows:
[image]

Question: You can clearly see some left margin given to the 'Hello World' text. Why is that? I have included no CSS file whatsoever! Also, how do I remove it?

Comment: Inspect it and see where it's getting styles from.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's because of default browser CSS. You can reset these using the following code.

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

You can add this CSS code to your global CSS file.

Answer (score 2):

You are actually asking how to remove the default style `margin: 8px` of the `body` element.

There are a lot of approaches, simplest might be normalizing and import it within `index.js`.

```
// styles.css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

// index.js
import "./styles.css";
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-volhard-58kzp?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```css
body, html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* Not supported in IE 6 & IE 7 */
}
```